# Get Username using GUID in Sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I have an issue with my SugarCRM reset password page. When a user visits the Reset Password form through the link provided through mail, he/she has to put the username. If the username is kept empty the form gets submitted but the password doesn't change. 
I want to either make username required field or fetch the username using GUID. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = BeanFactory::getBean('Users',$guid);
$username = $user->user_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The guid included in the password reset link is not the guid for that user (that would be a security risk). Instead, it is a guid to the users_password_link table. If you are using the guid passed in from such a link, then you could find the username by the following SQL statement:

`select users.user_name from users join users_password_link on users_password_link.username = users.user_name where users_password_link.id = '$guid';`

If you were working with the user's actual guid, egg's answer is the correct way to find the information using SugarCRM's best practices.